# ionic android app - links inside iframe not working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

When I click links inside the iframe nothing happens. I want to links in the iframe to be clickable links. is there a way to allow this?

```
<ion-view style="" title="IFRAME">
    <ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">
        <div style="" class="list card">
                <div class="item item-divider-android">Website</div>
            <div class="item item-body-android">
                <div style="">
                    <center>
<iframe src='{{trustSrc(website.src)}}' frameborder="0" width="100%" height="800" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
sandbox="allow-top-navigation">
```

to the iframe element.